# BigQuery imports from GoogleAds show all CPM related Fields with value 0

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api

Hello wonderful person!

I've followed [this](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer) guide to import google ads campaign info to a BigQuery database.

**My goal is to create a simple query that can be stored as a view and accessed from Data Studio to make a report. But some fields like AverageCpm are always set to 0.**

I also have a data studio report made using google ads as source for reference and I can access all the campaigns from the google ads platform.

**Here is the query I'm working on:**

```
SELECT
  c.ExternalCustomerId,
  c.CampaignName as name,
  c.CampaignStatus,
  cs.date as dia,
  SUM(cs.Impressions) AS Impressions,
  SUM(cs.Interactions) AS Interactions,
  AVG(cs.AverageCpm)  AS CPM,
  SUM(cs.Cost)  AS Cost
FROM
  `<DB>.google_ads.Campaign_<ACCOUNT_ID>` c
LEFT JOIN
  `<DB>.google_ads.CampaignStats_<ACCOUNT_ID>` cs
ON
  (c.CampaignId = cs.CampaignId
   AND cs._DATA_DATE BETWEEN
   DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -80 DAY) AND DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY))
WHERE
  c._DATA_DATE = c._LATEST_DATE
  and c.CampaignName = 'THE_NAME_OF_MY_CAMPAIGN'

GROUP BY
  1, 2, 3 , 4
ORDER BY
  CampaignName, dia
```

The field Impressions, returns with a value that is consistent with my reference datastudio report and the info I see in google ads stats, so I feel I'm in the right track.

**My problem is that some fields like CampaignStats.AverageCpm , CampaignStats.Cost are always 0**.

For example, the query:

```
Select * from `<DB>.google_ads.p_CampaignStats_<ACCOUNT_ID>` where AverageCpm >0;
```

**Returns with no results.**

I'm thinking permission problems? But I have administrator access to all the company's accounts.

Database is backfilled correctly.

I've tried generating a new dataset: Same problem and I don't see if there is a way to configure how google makes the imports.

What else could it be? What else can I do?

**Thank you very very much!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Roman Petrochenkov, [check his youtube channel](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCGVixrs0am6EoF9O16C5lpQ/featured) he is the best.

AVG(cs.AverageCpm) AS CPM, Is not correct
Since average of averages is not average of the total.

**You need to calculate CPM manually as SUM(Impressions)/SUM(NULLIF(Cost, 0)) as CPM**

Although, I would recommend against calculating it in the BQ and would recommend to calculate int in the BI (data studio in this case).